# IE form submit after second click on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, multipartform-data

i have a page containing multiple  includes of this jsp :

```
<script>
L_TYPE_FICHIER_INVALIDE='<stetag:libelle tag="L_TYPE_FICHIER_INVALIDE" inJavascript="true"/>';
L_FICHIER_ERREUR='<stetag:libelle tag="L_FICHIER_ERREUR" inJavascript="true" />';
L_FICHIER_UPLOAD_ERROR_TIMEOUT_KO='<stetag:libelle tag="L_FICHIER_UPLOAD_ERROR_TIMEOUT_KO" inJavascript="true" />';
</script>
<%-- Inputs --%>
<table class="tr_upload_container" id="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("id", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>_id">
    <tr>
       <td class="tr_upload_container_td">
          <iframe class="target_iframe" name="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("name", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>_form_iframe" style="display:none;" src="about:blank"></iframe>
          <form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/stecard/action/util/uploadTrFile_execute.action" name="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("name", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>_from" target="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("name", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>_form_iframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data">
             <input id="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("id", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>" name="file" type="file" style="width: 300px;display:none;" onchange="this.form.fileName.value = this.value; this.form.fileHolder.value = this.value;" />
             <input name="fileHolder" type="text" style="width: 200px;" readonly="readonly"/>
             <input name="button" type="button" class="IHMSwitch" onclick="$('#<%= pageContext.getAttribute("id", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>').click();" value="<stetag:libelle tag="L_UPLOAD_MARGE_LIB002"/>" /> 
             <input name="accept" type="hidden" value="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("accept", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>" />
             <input name="trFileUploadId" type="hidden" value="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("id", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>" />
             <input name="timeout" type="hidden" value="<%= pageContext.getAttribute("timeout", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) %>" />
             <% if(pageContext.getAttribute("fileName", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) == null) { %>
                <input class="fileName" name="fileName" type="hidden" value=""/>
             <% } %>
             <input type="hidden" name="<csrf:token-name/>" value="<csrf:token-value/>" />
             <input type="hidden" name="submitt" value="0" />
             <input type="submit" value="0" class="submit" style=""/>
          </form>
       </td>
       <td>
          <img class="uploading" alt="<stetag:libelle tag="L_FICHIER_UPLOADING"/>" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/stecard/images/loader.gif" style="display : none;"/>
          <img class="upload_success" alt="<stetag:libelle tag="L_FICHIER_UPLOAD_SUCCESS"/>" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/stecard/images/tick.png" style="display : none;"/>
          <img class="upload_error" alt="<stetag:libelle tag="L_FICHIER_UPLOAD_ERROR"/>" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/stecard/images/error.png" style="display : none;"/>
          <img class="upload_blank" alt="<stetag:libelle tag="L_UPLOAD_MARGE_LIB001"/>" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/stecard/images/blank.png" />
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

The form in this JSP is meant to be submitted in the iframe above it.

The `<input type="submit" value="0" class="submit" style=""/>` should do the job. but no it's not working in IE unless i click this button a second time.

I tried multiple workarrounds such as clicking the button using JS, or calling the submit method of the form. But none of those solved the problem.

Please help me.

Comment: is the first click focusing the page and the second clicking the button?  If you click on something on the page that is not the button, than click on the button, does it work on first try? Also helps to state the version of IE.

Comment: i found that this is a bug in IE : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878143/input-submit-only-working-after-second-click) but i really need a workaaround to solve